# Odd Jquery and AJAX bug in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a working AJAX request that updates a vote database when the user clicks an element.
The ccs of the element changes and the displayed amount of votes updates.

Here's some of my JS

```
function voteSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $("#"+postId).addClass('red').removeClass('blankUpVote'); //CSS Element

    $('#vote'+postId).html(data); //amount of votes is updated
}
```

where `postId` is declared as this.id of the element before.  I'm trying to set the identifier

```
$("#"+postId)
```

to

```
$("#post"+postId)
```

and change the id of the corresponding element in my template to

```
id="post{{ post.pk }}"
```

from

```
 id="{{ post.pk }}"
```

But it doesn't work! I get the exception `"ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'upVote12'"` when I run it.

The second part, where the amount of votes is updated is set up in the same way and it works.  Where the identifier is

```
$('#vote'+postId)
```

and the id of the corresponding element in the template is

```
id = "vote{{post.pk}}"
```

Can't figure it out!  I need to add a string in the id to make it different from other id's in the post container that will be using the same `post.pk` variable in the template.

It works for the second identifier but not the first.  Anyone have any idea of what might be going on?

Thanks

Comment: The `ValueError` exception comes from view. May be you are sending the post id to the view as `upVote12` when it should be `12` and most probably in your view you are trying to convert this in `int` e.g. int(postid) hence the `ValueError`. Show the view code. And point out the line of error.

Comment: Typically, you don't need ids for this sort of thing. Instead, work relative to the clicked element (`this` in the click handler) to discover the two corresponding elements, which can be selected by class - eg ".post" and ".vote". Not only do you avoid the need for ids, but execution is more efficient as selection by id is fundamentally slow.